# How to create custom menu in Magento admin panel? System>configuration>Custom

Tags: admin, menu, custom-menu, magento-1.9.4.1

How to create custom menu in Magento admin panel `system > configuration >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to create a menu in the admin area.

For this, you should create a simple extension. And in your extension, have `etc/adminhtml.xml` file in your extension and this content in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <your_menu_base>
            <title>Your Main Menu</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <child_menu>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <title>Your Sub Menu</title>
                </child_menu>
            </children>
        </your_menu_base>
     </menu>
</config>
```

**UPDATE**

To create a system menu and value field, add this file `etc/system.xml` and this content in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <my_tab translate="label" module="my_module">
            <label>My System Tab</label>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
        </my_tab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <my_option translate="label" module="my_module">
            <label>My System Config</label>
            <tab>my_tab </tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label">
                    <label>General Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <enable translate="label">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        </enable>
                    </fields>
               </general>
           </groups>
        </my_option>
   </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working in my admin top menu. i want to create side menu inside the system>configuration

Comment: check my update.

Comment: Thanks! its working..